# What's wrong with this Lucene TokenFilter?

Tags: lucene, tokenize

Disclaimer: I've been coding for 36 of the last 41 hours. I have a headache. And I can't figure out why this combining TokenFilter is returning 2 tokens, both the first token from the source stream.

```
public class TokenCombiner extends TokenFilter {

  /*
   * Recombines all tokens back into a single token using the specified delimiter.
   */
  public TokenCombiner(TokenStream in, int delimiter) {
    super(in);
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
  }
  int delimiter;


  private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
  private final OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);


  private boolean firstToken = true;
  int startOffset = 0;
  @Override
  public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    while (true){ 
        boolean eos = input.incrementToken(); //We have to process tokens even if they return end of file.
        CharTermAttribute token = input.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        if (eos && token.length() == 0) break; //Break early to avoid extra whitespace.
        if (firstToken){
            startOffset = input.getAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class).startOffset();
            firstToken = false;

        }else{
            termAtt.append(Character.toString((char)delimiter));
        }
        termAtt.append(token);
        if (eos) break;
    }
    offsetAtt.setOffset(startOffset, input.getAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class).endOffset());
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void reset() throws IOException {
    super.reset();
    firstToken = true;
    startOffset = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem here, is that you must realize both TokenCombiner and the producer it consumes (input) share and reuse the same attributes! So token == termAtt always (try adding an assert!).

Man, that sucks if you have been coding for 36 hours on a weekend... try this:

```
public class TokenCombiner extends TokenFilter {
  private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
  private final OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
  private final char separator;
  private boolean consumed; // true if we already consumed

  protected TokenCombiner(TokenStream input, char separator) {
    super(input);
    this.separator = separator;
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    if (consumed) {
      return false; // don't call input.incrementToken() after it returns false
    }
    consumed = true;

    int startOffset = 0;
    int endOffset = 0;

    boolean found = false; // true if we actually consumed any tokens
    while (input.incrementToken()) {
      if (!found) {
        startOffset = offsetAtt.startOffset();
        found = true;
      }
      sb.append(termAtt);
      sb.append(separator);
      endOffset = offsetAtt.endOffset();
    }

    if (found) {
      assert sb.length() > 0; // always: because we append separator
      sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
      clearAttributes();
      termAtt.setEmpty().append(sb);
      offsetAtt.setOffset(startOffset, endOffset);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void reset() throws IOException {
    super.reset();
    sb.setLength(0);
    consumed = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So is incrementToken() supposed to return true even if the current token is the last token available?  (BTW, are there any docs on designing TokenStreams? The javadocs don't contain enough details (like this).

Comment: scroll to the bottom of http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html and check out the workflow described in http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html ... let me know what details we should add to the documentation!